# Bound mismatch with Generic Types

Tags: java

After one day searching I decided to ask your helps guys :-)
here is my issue: 
I need to write coverter for some pojos.

```
public abstract class Answer<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {//some code}

public class BooleanAnswer extends Answer<Boolean> {//some code}

public abstract class AnswerDMO<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {//some code}

public class BooleanAnswerDMO extends AnswerDMO<Boolean>  {//some code} 

public interface Converter<I, O> {
O convert(I input);
}

public abstract class AnswerConverter<A extends Answer<Serializable>, J extends AnswerDMO<Serializable>>
                                        implements Converter<A, J>, Serializable {
@Override
public J convert(A input) {
    // some code
}
}

public class BooleanAnswerConverter extends AnswerConverter<BooleanAnswer, BooleanAnswerDMO>
{
    @Override
    public BooleanAnswerDMO convert(BooleanAnswer input) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error on the BooleanAnswerConverter, the parameter BooleanAnswer is not within its bound, should extend Answer
I tried many combination but couldnt get it right.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `A` and `J` extends `Answer` and `AnswerDMO`, and they have the type, you must change the `AnswerConverter` from:

```
public abstract class AnswerConverter<A extends Answer<Serializable>, J extends AnswerDMO<Serializable>>
```

To:

```
public abstract class AnswerConverter<A extends Answer, J extends AnswerDMO>
```

`Answer` and `AnswerDMO` has the type that is forcing the `Serializable`. Boolean in you example. `Answer<Serializable>` will try to ensure that the final implementation is this one, not a generic Answer.

This change result in correct compile of class:

```
public class BooleanAnswerConverter extends AnswerConverter<BooleanAnswer, BooleanAnswerDMO> {
    @Override
    public BooleanAnswerDMO convert(BooleanAnswer input) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but a working solution would be

```
abstract class AnswerConverter<A extends Answer<? extends Serializable>,
        J extends AnswerDMO<? extends Serializable>> implements Converter<A, J>, Serializable {
```